# Is the constructor of a derived class called when we new it using a base pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor

```
Class Shape {
    virtual Shape() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() = 0;
}

Class Circle : Public Shape {
    Circle();
    ~Circle();
    // Something ...
}

int main () {
Shape* s = new Circle();
delete s;
}
```

Is it calling the constructor of Circle? Even if it is of different name of the constructo of Shape?
When you delete s, are you calling the destructor of Circle?

Comment: Is this C#? If so, you might want to add that as a tag.

Comment: Is this supposed to be C++?  If so, it's not legal to mark constructors virtual.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ a constructor cannot be virtual.

The code you have provided is not valid c++.

Here are is the corrected code, you can see it run here: http://codepad.org/2fDc4S3e
The output of the program should answer all your questions. I recommend you play with the code to answer any other questions you might have.

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape() = 0;
};

Shape::~Shape() { std::cout << "Shape dtor called" << std::endl;} // Since you declared the destructor pure virtual you must define it

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle() { std::cout << "Circle ctor called." << std::endl; }
    ~Circle() { std::cout << "Circle dtor called." << std::endl; }
    // Something ...
};

int main () 
{
  Shape* s = new Circle(); // This will call the constructor of Circle
  delete s; // This will call the destructor of Circle and then the dtor Shape.
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the dtor of Circle will be called:

- Because Shape's dtor is virtual, any class inheriting from it will have a virual dtor.
- This mean the dtor is not called directly but through the v-table: when you "delete s" it calls s.dtor() which is calls the right item in the v-table, which is Circle's dtor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can't be virtual.

```
class Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    Circle() {};
    ~Circle() {};
};

int main() {
    Shape *s = new Circle();
    delete s;
}
```

Yes, `new Circle()` calls the constructor for Circle. This is because the expression `new <type><optional initializer>` allocates memory sufficient for  and then initializes it by calling the appropriate constructor (or other initialization for non-class types). Nothing about this needs to be virtual because you have explicitly states the most derived type.

The result of `new Circle()` is a pointer to a Circle. Assigning this type to a variable of type pointer to Shape involves an implicit conversion. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the Circle's base Shape sub-object. Again, nothing about this is virtual, because the Shape is not a virtual base, it's just a regular base object and it's location inside the Circle is known statically.

`delete s` does call the Circle destructor. This does use virtual dispatch. The compiler knows it's deleting a Shape, and the destructor of Shape is virtual, so it looks up the appropriate destructor, which is `~Circle()`, and calls it. If Shape's destructor was not vitual (and actually had a definition somewhere) then this would not be done and only the Shape object would be destructed, not the Circle object, and the deallocation might not be done correctly. The behavior would be undefined.